# Coroutines - Function vs Procedure

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When transforming (async function that needs to do some backgorund work to return a value) to sync function with coroutines one can use suspendCoroutine, as in the following extension i did to FusedLocationProviderClient :

```
private suspend fun FusedLocationProviderClient.colastLocation(): Location = suspendCoroutine {
    lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { l -> l?.run { it.resume(l) } ?: run{ it.resumeWithException(Exception("location is null"))} }.addOnFailureListener { e -> it.resumeWithException(e) }
}
```

But what if i want to make an async procedure run sync? (procedure = function that i dont care of its returned value, i just want to wait for it to finish)

I can still use suspendCoroutine as i did for addGeofence here:

```
private suspend fun GeofencingClient.coaddGeofences(geofencingRequest: GeofencingRequest, broadcast: PendingIntent?) : Void = suspendCoroutine {
    addGeofences(geofencingRequest,broadcast).addOnSuccessListener { v ->  it.resume(v) }.addOnFailureListener { e -> it.resumeWithException(e) }
}
```

But it feels a little hacky working with that Void object, maybe there is a more natural way to do that? e.g run async job and make it sync with coroutines when i dont care for the value (if returned - its a success, else it would throw an exception).

Theoretically i would expect doing something like that :

```
private suspend fun GeofencingClient.coaddGeofences(geofencingRequest: GeofencingRequest, broadcast: PendingIntent?) = suspendCoroutine {
    addGeofences(geofencingRequest,broadcast).addOnSuccessListener { v ->  it.resume() }.addOnFailureListener { e -> it.throwException(e) }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `Unit` (the implicit "nothing" return type) instead of `Void`? There generally isn't ever a reason to use `Void` in Kotlin.

Comment: If you want to wait for a suspend function to finish, just use `runBlocking`.

Answer (score 0):

As Moira has mentioned, you can just use Kotlin's `Unit` object. From `Unit` `s Javadoc:

> The type with only one value: the `Unit` object. This type corresponds to the `void` type in Java.

So your procedure code will look like:

```
private suspend fun GeofencingClient.coaddGeofences(geofencingRequest: GeofencingRequest, broadcast: PendingIntent?) = suspendCoroutine<Unit> {
    addGeofences(geofencingRequest,broadcast).addOnSuccessListener { it.resume(Unit) }.addOnFailureListener { e -> it.resumeWithException(e) }
}
```